# replace an 's' at the end of the word if there's not an 's' before it

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
.replace(/([^s]?s)$/, '')
```

I thought `[^abc]` meant "not any of these characters" but in the code above, it's replacing the s at the end of the word only if there's an s before it. How would I make this regex into: replace the s at the end of the word, only if there's no s before it?

Comment: Did you mean to say *remove* instead of *replace*?

Comment: Mmmh. `"fas".replace(/([^s]?s)$/, '')` results in `"f"`. So it seems it *does* replace the last `s` (and the preceding character).

Comment: I don't want to vote up this question because the OP's reputation is currently "1,337"...

Comment: GregL, that's hilarious... it's gone now though, guess i'm normal like everyone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is with a negative lookbehind, but JavaScript does not support this. So instead we'll just use a backreference:

```
.replace(/([^s])s\b/, '$1')
```

This matches two characters at the end of a word, the first being something besides "s", the second being "s", and replaces them both with the first matched character (the non-"s").

Incidentally, this regex will ignore a word consisting purely of the letter "s". I'm not sure how you intended that case to be handled. If you delete the trailing "s" on that word, then you've deleted the entire word.

---

The reason your original regex doesn't work is because you have the `?` character, which makes that non-s match optional, and you're not actually providing any replacement string, which means that if the non-s atom matches, then it'll get deleted. In other words, running that on `"foos"` will result in `"fo"` instead of `"foo"`. And running that on `"foss"` will produce `"fos"` (because it skipped the non-s atom).

Comment: +1 for describing how it works.  Regex can be so obscure when you only know _some_ of its tricks.